# DT_DEBUG not filled on dlopen

Tags: gdb, elf, dynamic-linking

A target library "lib42.so" has DT_DEBUG entry in the .dynamic section.

After dlopen("lib42.so", RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_NOW) succeded, r_debug->d_un.d_ptr is equal to zero. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably check the dynamic linker source code to be sure but I suspect that `DT_DEBUG` is only filled for the main binary and not the additional modules.